# Deleting a node from a binary tree

Tags: c++11, pointers, binary-tree

I was trying to implement a binary tree in C++, but my *deleteNode* function was not working properly.  What is wrong with my *deleteNode* function?

```
template<class T>
class TreeNode {
public:
    T data;
    TreeNode<T> *right;
    TreeNode<T> *left;

    TreeNode(T data) {
        this->data = data;
        right = NULL;
        left = NULL;
    }
};

template<class T>
class Tree {
public:
    TreeNode<T> *root;

    Tree() {
        root = NULL;
    }

    void deleteNode(T data) {
        TreeNode<T> *current = root;
        TreeNode<T> *parent = NULL;

        while (current != NULL && current->data != data) {
            parent = current;
            if (current->data < data) {
                current = current->right;
            } else if (current->data > data) {
                current = current->left;
            }
        }

        if (current == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        if (current->left == NULL || current->right == NULL) {
            TreeNode<T> *newCurrent = (current->left == NULL) ? current->right : current->left;

            if (parent == NULL) {
                root = newCurrent;
            } else if (current == parent->left) {
                parent->left = newCurrent;
            } else {
                parent->right = newCurrent;
            }

            delete current;
        }
        else {
            TreeNode<T> *successorParent = current;
            TreeNode<T> *successor = current->right;

            while (successor->left != NULL) {
                successorParent = successor;
                successor = successor->left;
            }

            current->data = successor->data;

            if (successorParent->left == successor) {
                successorParent->left = successor->right;
            } else {
                successorParent->right = successor->right;
            }

            delete successor;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to debug my function and changed something few times, but it did not work at any time.

(What about the new version of ***deleteNode***? It is working, but not in all cases and I do not know why.)

Comment: `while(current != NULL || current->data != data)` This check doesn't make sense. When `current` is in fact `NULL`, it goes ahead and tries to access `current->data` through a null pointer.

Comment: You should not be calling `free` in C++ code -- use `delete` (and `new` to allocate)

Comment: In the new version I used `delete` instead of `free` and I think two child case handled better.